# jqGrid is not displaying JSON data

Tags: jquery, json, jqgrid

I'm using jqGrid to display some json data, but the grid is not displaying anything when I run the code and I receive **no error** message in my console.
Here is my js code:

```
$("#gridWall").jqGrid({
    datatype: 'json',
    data: data,
    colNames: ['Id', 'Title', 'Artist', 'ISRC'],
    colModel: [
               {name: 'Id', index: 'music_video_id', width: 100, editable: false},
               {name: 'Title', index: 'title', width: 150, editable: false},
               {name: 'Artist', index: 'artist_name', width: 200, editable: false},
               {name: 'ISRC', index: 'isrc', width: 150, editable: false}

    ],
    pager: '#gridpagerWall',
    loadonce: true,
    rowNum: 100,
    rowList: [100, 200, 300],
    sortname: 'title',
    sortorder: 'asc',
    jsonReader: {
        repeatitems: true,
        root: "contents",
        page: '1',
        total: "number"

    },
    viewrecords: true,
    gridview: true,
    hidegrid: false,
    caption: 'Wall builder',
    editUrl: 'clientArray',
   })
```

And my JSON data goes like this:

```
{"number":50,"type":5,"contents":[{"title":"xxx","isrc":"xxx","artist_name":"xx","music_video_id":"1"},...]}
```

Does anybody knows how can i solve my problem?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your json is valid using [json Validator](http://jsonlint.com/) .
Then change `data:data,` to `url :data`
I hope variable data contains a valid url.